# Reduction of copper oxide by hydrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, hydrogen

In the concluding part of my [previous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/reduction-of-copper-oxide-by-hydrogen-in-the-lab), wouldn't there be an explosion near the hole in the tube from where the excess hydrogen is coming out instead of a steadily burning flame?

Comment: Please refer to the previous question.

Comment: Pure hydrogen does not explode. When mixed with air, it does. Don't let them mix.

Comment: But if it is pure hydrogen, and no air, how does it even burn with a flame.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar It may be questionable to bump old questions by minor updates.

Comment: @Poutnik I am sorry but I didn't understand what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Poutnik Nisarg wanted to link the previous question which was not done before. Such edits are welcomed. It may even attract answers after being left unanswered for years.